# Converting XML string to Spark Dataframe in Databricks

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, databricks

how can I build a Spark dataframe from a string which contains XML code?

I can easily do it, if the code is saved in a file

```
dfXml = (sqlContext.read.format("xml")
           .options(rowTag='my_row_tag')
           .load(xml_file_name))
```

However as said I have to build the dataframe from a string which contains regular XML.

Thank you

Mauro

Answer (score 1):

You can parse xml string without spark xml connector. Using below udf, You can convert xml string into json & then do your transformations on that.

I have taken one sample xml string & stored in catalog.xml file.

```
/tmp> cat catalog.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?><catalog><book id="bk101"><author>Gambardella, Matthew</author><title>XML Developer's Guide</title><genre>Computer</genre><price>44.95</price><publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date><description>An in-depth look at creating applications with XML.</description></book></catalog>
<?xml version="1.0"?><catalog><book id="bk102"><author>Ralls, Kim</author><title>Midnight Rain</title><genre>Fantasy</genre><price>5.95</price><publish_date>2000-12-16</publish_date><description>A former architect battles corporate zombies, an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen of the world.</description></book></catalog>
```

**Please note below code is in scala, This will help you to implement same logic in python.**

```
scala> val df = spark.read.textFile("/tmp/catalog.xml")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[String] = [value: string]

scala> import org.json4s.Xml.toJson
import org.json4s.Xml.toJson

scala> import org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods.{compact, parse}
import org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods.{compact, parse}

scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

implicit class XmlToJson(data: String) {
    def json(root: String) = compact {
      toJson(scala.xml.XML.loadString(data)).transformField {
        case (field,value) => (field.toLowerCase,value)
      } \ root.toLowerCase
    }
    def json = compact(parse(data))
  }

val parseUDF = udf { (data: String,xmlRoot: String) => data.json(xmlRoot.toLowerCase)}


// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

defined class XmlToJson
parseUDF: org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.UserDefinedFunction = UserDefinedFunction(<function2>,StringType,Some(List(StringType, StringType)))

scala> val json = df.withColumn("value",parseUDF($"value",lit("catalog")))
json: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [value: string]

scala> val json = df.withColumn("value",parseUDF($"value",lit("catalog"))).select("value").map(_.getString(0))
json: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[String] = [value: string]

scala> val bookDF = spark.read.json(json).select("book.*")
bookDF: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [author: string, description: string ... 5 more fields]

scala> bookDF.printSchema
root
 |-- author: string (nullable = true)
 |-- description: string (nullable = true)
 |-- genre: string (nullable = true)
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- price: string (nullable = true)
 |-- publish_date: string (nullable = true)
 |-- title: string (nullable = true)


scala> bookDF.show(false)
+--------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------+-----+-----+------------+---------------------+
|author              |description                                                                                                         |genre   |id   |price|publish_date|title                |
+--------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------+-----+-----+------------+---------------------+
|Gambardella, Matthew|An in-depth look at creating applications with XML.                                                                 |Computer|bk101|44.95|2000-10-01  |XML Developer's Guide|
|Ralls, Kim          |A former architect battles corporate zombies, an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen of the world.|Fantasy |bk102|5.95 |2000-12-16  |Midnight Rain        |
+--------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------+-----+-----+------------+---------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

On Scala, class "XmlReader" can be used for convert RDD[String] to DataFrame:

```
    val result = new XmlReader().xmlRdd(spark, rdd)
```

If you have Dataframe as input, it can be converted to RDD[String] easily.