# Parse an XML string with Spark Streaming

Tags: scala, apache-spark, xml-parsing, spark-streaming

I'm trying to receive an XML from an MQTT broker:

```scala
  val df = spark.readStream
    .format("org.apache.bahir.sql.streaming.mqtt.MQTTStreamSourceProvider")
    .option...
    .load()
    .selectExpr("CAST(payload AS STRING)")
```

then consume it, for example:

```scala
  val query = df.writeStream
    .outputMode("append")
    .format("console")
    .start()
```

Point is, I'd like to parse it (column `$payload` contains a string) and then convert it (eg. in JSON) before outputting/saving it.

I tried the following approaches:

1. Append `.format("com.databricks.spark.xml")`

   but it doen't support Structured Streaming.
2. An UDF function

   - Using `scala.xml.XML.loadString` gives me a `scala.MatchError: scala.xml.Elem (of class scala.reflect.internal.Types$ClassNoArgsTypeRef)` (seems like is not a valid type for UDF functions)
   - Using `import com.databricks.spark.xml.functions.from_xml` is problematic, because it wants a prior schema (which I don't really have, I tried to take it with `import com.databricks.spark.xml.functions.from_xml.schema_of_xml` on the fly with two approaches:

     - `.withColumn("xml", from_xml(col("payload"), schema_of_xml(Seq(col("payload").toString()).toDS)))` gives me an empty column.
     - using `udf((s: String) => from_xml_string(s, schema_of_xml(Seq(s).toDS)))` gives me an `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Schema for type org.apache.spark.sql.Row is not supported`, but I don't have a predefined schhema for my data, so...

Comment: You can check this post  - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62379533/convert-streaming-xml-into-json-in-spark/62381019#62381019 & upvote if it helps .. :)

Comment: Also you can check - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61333280/converting-xml-string-to-spark-dataframe-in-databricks/61335448#61335448 both are different.

Comment: @Srinivas can you please provide a reference link to know about how to create the schema_json

Comment: I don't have any references to give you. I have created schema json based on final table output and applied to data.